# This text input goes unchecked every time I press a key. In order to continue typing I have to click it again. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The textInput component goes unchecked on every key I press, making it completely useless. I tried with useMemo, with a custom component. Nothing. This still doesn't work.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { setPageTitle } from '../store/themeConfigSlice';
import { getCustomers } from '../services/customerService';
import { DataTable, ActionIcon, TextInput } from 'mantine-datatable';
import { IconSearch, IconX } from '@tabler/icons-react';

const Customers = (): any => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([] as any);
  const [customersNotEmpty, setCustomersNotEmpty] = useState(false as boolean);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setPageTitle('Customers'));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCustomers()
      .then((response) => setCustomers(response.data))
      .then(() => setCustomersNotEmpty(true));
  }, [customersNotEmpty]);

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');

  const filteredData = customers?.filter((item: any) =>
    item.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
  );

  const NameColumnHeader = () => (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
      <span className="mr-2">Name</span>
      <TextInput
        className=""
        label=""
        placeholder="Search by Name..."
        value={filter}
        onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.currentTarget.value)}
        rightSection={
          filter && (
            <ActionIcon
              size="sm"
              variant="transparent"
              c="dimmed"
              onClick={() => setFilter('')}
            >
              <IconX size={14} />
            </ActionIcon>
          )
        }
      />
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="flex space-x-2 rtl:space-x-reverse">
        <li>
          <Link to="/" className="text-primary hover:underline">
            Dashboard
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="before:content-['/'] ltr:before:mr-2 rtl:before:ml-2">
          <span>Customers</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div className="flex flex-col xl:flex-row gap-5 relative mt-5">
        <DataTable
          noRecordsText="No results match your search query"
          highlightOnHover
          className="whitespace-nowrap table-hover"
          records={filteredData}
          columns={[
            { accessor: 'client_id', title: '#' },
            { accessor: 'name', title: <NameColumnHeader /> },
            { accessor: 'code', title: 'Code' },
            { accessor: 'address_city', title: 'City' },
            { accessor: 'address_province', title: 'Province' },
            { accessor: 'country', title: 'Country' },
            { accessor: 'vat_number', title: 'VAT' },
            { accessor: 'id', title: 'ID' },
          ]}
          totalRecords={customers?.length}
          recordsPerPage={10}
          page={1}
          onPageChange={() => null}
          recordsPerPageOptions={[0]}
          onRecordsPerPageChange={() => null}
          sortStatus={undefined}
          onSortStatusChange={undefined}
          minHeight={200}
          paginationText={({ from, to, totalRecords }) =>
            `Showing  ${from} to ${to} of ${totalRecords} entries`
          }
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Customers;
```

I don't know what to do. Both TextInput and DataTable components are from Mantine.
How can I get a simple, working, table with filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above defines `NameColumnHeader` inside a component named `Customers`.

A component is a JavaScript function. When a component "renders", you are simply running that JavaScript function.

You have defined a function (let's call it `B()`) inside of a function (`A()`). Every single time that `A()` is run, it will ***recreate*** `B()`. It is not the same `B()` as in the previous run.

In React terms: you have defined a component `<B>` inside of the code of component `<A>`. Each time that `<A>` renders, you get a new component called `<B>`.

Do not define components inside of components. 99.47% of the time you will not be happy with the results.